# Idiomatic function overloading

Tags: haskell

I googled a lot but still confused about the most idiomatic way to overloading function in Haskell. Given:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> Double
foo :: String -> String -> Double
foo :: String -> Double
foo :: Char -> Integer-> Integer -> Integer -> String
```

(not sure if I covered all the possible cases) how would you make it idiomatic (type classes?)

Comment: habe a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses for a good intro to type classes... (but the kind of function overloading you're looking for is probably simply not possible and neither desirable in haskell)

Comment: your question isn't very specific. what exactly are you trying to achieve? concrete example? the simple answer is that one function can only have on function signature in haskell, not four like in your example.

Comment: I can maybe see the first three being combined to something like `foo :: FooArgs -> Double`, where `FooArgs` is a sum of `(Int, String)`, `(String, String)`, and `String`, but the last should probably be a separate function.

Comment: Unless the first `String` argument itself determines what to return, you can't differentiate between (2) and (3) due to currying. Should `foo "bar"` return a `Double` or a function of type `String -> Double`?

Comment: I don't know why you are editing your question into gibberish, but please stop.

Comment: I have already asked to delete this question. It doesn't express exactly what I meant. The answer is wrong, but cos of it I cannot remove the question. Can you please delete this question for me? People just voting down without a reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Technically, you can do like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}                                          

class Foo a where
    foo :: a

instance Foo (Int -> String -> Double) where
    foo = ...

instance Foo (String -> String -> Double) where
    foo = ...

instance Foo (String -> Double) where
    foo = ...

instance Foo (Char -> Integer -> Integer -> String) where
    foo = ...
```

But, I think it's usually bad way, because I believe that these functions have random properties, you just union them to group by your mind and in the future somebody will hard to understand the `foo` function.